QBism makes perfect sense, but what about the rest of the world?
As I understand it, QBism is an epistemological interpretation of quantum mechanics, much like the Copenhagen interpretation. The state of a quantum system, described by a wave function, is not something that exists objectively, but only the knowledge of the agent (that is, the person) performing the measurements. This is completely understandable. From a QBism perspective, quantum mechanics is not a theory about what reality is, but a theory about how we interact with that reality? That is, the question “what is reality” is not asked in quantum mechanics at all; quantum mechanics should not answer such a question. Do I understand correctly?

"What is reality" is a question for philosophers. In physics, reality is what we observe and measure.

No physical model ever claimed to explain what reality is. That is never ever the goal of physics. The goal of any model in physics to predict observations. What that implies about reality is, frankly, completely irrelevant in physics.

Physicists very much want to know what reality is, but they sometimes say "what the underlying theory is". That is the same question, but makes it more clear that there can be a sequance of answers, getting more and more refined. And that perhaps we'll never reach an ultimate answer. (Although physicists would like to have that ultimate answer very much! A theory of everything, they would call it.)
